# Advice on learning assembly optimization and SIMD instructions

Tags: xcode, assembly, llvm, inline-assembly

I've been a C/C++ programmer for many years, but I never learned assembly. I am trying to learn assembly now, with the ultimate goal of being able to write my own optimized routines for math operations using SIMD instructions. I know that C/C++ libraries wrapping SIMD optimized routines exist, but for educational reasons I want to learn how to do it myself.

I would really appreciate some tips on how to get me started and more specifically:

1. I am using a QuadCore i7 MacBook Pro (retina) for my dev machine (64 bit). I want to setup an environment, a sandbox, where I can experiment and write code as I learn. Is it possible to use XCode (LLVM) and inline assembly for this and if so, how would I go about it ? (A simple example of inline assembly utilizing an SSE instruction would be great)
2. I am primarily interested in learning how to optimise math operations with assembly, not necessarily programming entirely in assembly. If inline assembly is not the right way to go about it, what would be the alternative or the recommended method?

I am a beginner, and of course have a lot to learn. I do have a specific goal however and that would be the guiding principle in my studies. Any advice on how to go about my studies will also be appreciated.

Thanks a bunch to all who answer and pardon my ignorance as I get familiar with the subject more.

Comment: Consider taking up AMP or CUDA instead

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those. My goal is to learn assembly and write for the chip, but those are certainly interesting, particularly CUDA

Comment: If it's about learning the mechanics/frame of mind, that's okay. If it's about actually making the difference, general purpose GPU programming is likely to be more relevant

Comment: Nice Disassembler (Demo Version) http://www.hopperapp.com. I used the demo to get some insights about how my code gets compiled. BTW I heard that Apple eventually goes Non-Intel.